# Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead

Tags: stream, ros, vp8

I am using [web video server](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/web_video_server) with ros eloquent in ubuntu 18 LTS. When I try to access vp8 or vp9 or h264 stream from web video server, I will get below error and I cant able to play the video in the web browser.

`Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.`

How to get rid of this error?[image]

[image]